# Loading prototype cells from a Xib

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib

Most of my app runs on a storyboard however I have to customise the collection view layout significantly based on the device screen size. I have pulled the controller with the collection view out into Xib files for each screen size and I load the appropriate one. My cells are custom and designed using the prototype cells feature. When working with prototype cells in a storyboard everything loaded fine however it seems that now they are in a Xib I have to user the `registerNib` method for each prototype cell of I get a crash when loading the cells. So in `viewDidLoad` I call that method several times (once for each reuse identifier). I'm getting a crash still though.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7f8c0afbd370> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key collectionView
```

Normally with this error I'd assume an outlet not connected correctly but everything looks good.  The crash occurs when I try to dequeue a cell.

Any ideas how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake. I should have been registering the cell class not the nib the controller was in.